# Ping range of IP addresses

Tags: powershell

I need to read IP address and subnet mask from a file  and display all appropriate ip addresses with status. This command can display a list of addresses:

```
New-Object System.Net.Networkinformation.Ping.send("ip.$_")
```

but it requires only IP address. How to make to be able to use a mask too?

**File example:**

```
192.168.0.10
255.255.255.0
```

Comment: So you want PowerShell to pull in an IP of `192.168.0.1` and say subnet mask provided is `255.255.255.224 /27`. The end result is to `ping` the `calculated` range of IPs `192.168.0.1 - 192.168.0.30`?

Comment: @Shawn Melton exactly!

Comment: See this script https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/List-the-IP-addresses-in-a-60c5bb6b (last update : today `:-)`)

Comment: Please provide sample content of your text file, and the version of PowerShell you are working under.

Comment: @ShawnMelton powershell v1.0

Comment: Look at invoke ping, by my friend Warren Edge

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Warren Frame wrote this great utility, based off of work from Shay Levy and Boe Prox, titled [Invoke-Ping](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Invoke-Ping-Test-in-b553242a).  You can provide a set of IP addresses like this:

```
Invoke-Ping -ComputerName 192.186.0.1,192.168.0.2
```

[Mark Gossa](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-Subnet-db45ec74) wrote a utility to figure out valid IPs for a given subnet mask, using this syntax:

```
Get-IPs -Subnets "10.0.2.0/24","10.0.4.0/24"
```

If we combine the two...

```
invoke-ping -ComputerName (get-ips -Subnets "192.168.0.10/24")
```

This will return the Pingable status of all computers in that range.  This should be a good jumping off point for you.  And, Warren's already done the work of spreading the ping across a range of IPs, meaning you can ping 1000 PCs in something like 10 seconds.

If you add -Quiet to `Invoke-Ping`, you'll get a list of just the valid (online) IPs at the time it was run.

```
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.11
192.168.0.12
192.168.0.13
192.168.0.15
192.168.0.16
192.168.0.18
192.168.0.21
192.168.0.22
192.168.0.9
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply.It is a very useful programs but I unfortunately have to solve my problem without the use of any software.

Comment: These are just powershell functions. Click the link and download them to see how they work. No software here.

Comment: Your reply makes me feel that maybe you don't know how to use functions like this. It's easy! Download them, and you'll see they are plain text files. Copy and paste them into your own script to use them. You'll need both of the ones I linked. Then, below where you've pasted them, just have the example I gave. That's it! Let me know if you get stuck but this is the answer to your question.

Answer (score 3):

Please try this script, it can be used to ping multiple hosts and you will get the status of each of them.

Change the IP address range in the script according to yours.

> ```
> $ping = New-Object System.Net.Networkinformation.Ping
> 1..254 | % { $ping.send("192.168.100.$_") | select address, status }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You can't ping range of addresses in single ping request due to ping protocol restrictions.

To achieve what you want you need to convert ranges into lists of IP addresses and ping them one by one (possibly in parallel).

Comment: I posted my own answer, let me know what you think. It is possible to ping a range at the same time, using community produced tools.

Comment: @FoxDeploy good links - useful post. I see that it was bad choice of words on my part - edited.

Answer (score 0):

A more modern approach would be to use the [WFTools](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/WFTools/):

```ps
Install-Module WFTools -Force -AllowClobber -Confirm:$false;
Import-Module WFTools;
```

You can than use it like this:

```ps
New-IPRange -Start 10.0.0.0 -End 10.0.0.255 `
| Invoke-Ping `
| Where { $_.Status -ne "No Response" } `
| Select -Property Address
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the network address and how many possible hosts in that network, you can modify the script below to work for you.

1..254 | foreach {test-connection ("10.1.80.$_") -count 1 -delay 1 -erroraction "silentlycontinue"}

Comment: I don't understand the code you have written, could you mention what language it is?